# What do you call words that look like a negation but are not?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I can be *nonplussed* (in fact that is practically the ground state of my existence), but not *plussed*. I can also be *indifferent*; but if you are *different*, that doesn't mean you care, either. What do you call it when a word looks like the negation of another word but is not? The kind of words that Terry Pratchett takes delight in?

(possible 2nd question) I had started by looking up *wittingly*, seeing that I've never seen it used except in the phrase "wittingly or unwittingly", or [ironically](http://www.ghostofaflea.com/archives/015435.html), as the opposite of unwittingly. There might even be another class of word like "wittingly", words that are only ever used *with* their opposite.

Comment: Don't forget "inflammable," which means the same thing as "flammable"...

Comment: I extend this question to pertain to French for those interested: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/11743/5306

Comment: @JeffSahol, What does "practically the ground state of my existence" mean?

Comment: @LePressentiment, Why is the link removed?

Comment: @Pacerier My question was downvoted to -1 and so was automatically deleted. But please feel free to request its undeletion.

Comment: @Pacerier It is a joke..."Ground State" is from physics...basically means "I am like this all the time"

Comment: @LePressentiment, I've seen many threads with -1 votes... so it couldn't be automatically deleted just because of that. Btw, I couldn't even see the link.. how to request for its undeletion?

Comment: @Pacerier Thank you for your support. Alas, one must write a post on the associated Meta website: I did this for you at http://meta.linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/623/5306. But please feel free to explain your reasons there too. Does this help?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It seems they are called [Unpaired Words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unpaired_word) (maybe the best definition) or [Absent Antonyms](http://www.2wheels.org.uk/return/absent-antonyms.asp).

> **Unpaired Words**
>   An unpaired word is one that, according to the usual rules of the language, would appear to have a related word but does not. Such words usually have a prefix or suffix that would imply that there is an antonym, with the prefix or suffix being absent or opposite.
>   Many unpaired words are the result of one of the words disappearing from popular usage, though others were never part of a pairing and just begin with the same letters as used in common prefixes. The classification of a word as “unpaired” can be problematic, as a word thought to be unattested might reappear in real-world usage

You can find some examples [here](http://www.rinkworks.com/words/negatives.shtml), but I'll list the majority of them here anyway for easy reference.

> 1. **Words with no positive forms:**
>      Debunk; defenestrate; dejected; disconsolate; disdain; disgruntled; dishevelled; dismayed; disrupt; feckless; gormless; impetuous; impromptu; inane; incessant; inchoate; incognito; incommunicado; indomitable; ineffable; inept; inert; infernal; inhibited; insidious; insipid; insouciant; intact; invert; misgivings; misnomer; nonchalant; noncommittal; nondescript; nonpareil; nonplussed; unbeknownst; ungainly; unswerving; untold; untoward.
> 2. **Words with uncommon positive forms:**
>      Disarray; disconcerting; immaculate; impeccable; inadvertent; incapacitated; incorrigible; inevitable; innocent; inscrutable; insensate; insufferable; interminable; unbridled; unflappable; unfurl; unkempt; unmitigated; unrequited; unruly; unthinkable; unwieldy.
> 3. **Suffixes (asterisk means "word not existing"):**
>
>    - Reckless/*Reckful
>    - Indefatigable/*defatigable -> fatigable
>    - Flammable-Inflammable (not antonyms)

Comment: _Unpaired Words_ is nice, and clearly the best answer.

Comment: One of my favorite words, _disambiguate_ is on the unpaired words list. Can't believe I didn't think of it.

Comment: Some of them are loanwords, like _nonchalant_ (French) or _incommunicado_ (Spanish).

Comment: Indeed, many of them are! I would venture to guess that almost all of the 'in-' words were borrowed from Latin at some point or another, but I am too lazy to look up the etymology. But disambiguate is a clear example of an unpaired word that is not a loan word, so I'm satisfied.

Comment: Another minor point: looking over this list again, I have to disagree that _debunk_ is an unpaired word. It just means to remove the [bunk(2)](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bunk) from something; the prefix _de-_ may be applied to a noun to denote its removal. Compare _declaw_, which is not the opposite of _to claw_, but rather the removal of _a claw_.

Comment: The contrary of _debunk_ is not _bunk_ though, it's _confirm_.

Comment: Quite so, and that shouldn't surprise us at all. Would you expect _spire_ to be the contrary of _inspire_? I wouldn't, because _inspire_ is based on a different meaning of the prefix _in-_. Likewise, _debunk_ is based on a different meaning of _de-_ than, for example, _demystify_.

Comment: Thanks, @Alemanno, I knew this had to be something that had been seriously discussed somewhere but all I'd found were lists of jokes based on unpaired words. So I guess "wittingly" would fall into the list of words with uncommon positive forms?

Comment: I was thinking the same thing as @senderle. In some cases the antonym is missing because it would make no sense whatsoever. ("delouse" was the example that came to mind in my case).

Comment: @JeffSahol: Sorry for being late but you know, Time Zones, when you wrote I was asleep I guess :D Anyway, _unwittingly_ has _wittingly_ as an antonym, so I'm not sure whether it falls on that list...

Comment: @Alenanno, Why is the "de" in  "dejected" considered negation and not simply part of the word itself? For example, the "de" in "decimeter", "deadline", "decrement", "deployer", "dejeuner", "devolving", "deserting", "demonical" are not considered to be negations.

Comment: @Pacerier I'm not sure I understand your question. The etymology for "dejected" shows that "de-" comes from the Latin verb [*dēĭcĕre*](http://www.online-latin-dictionary.com/latin-english-dictionary.php?lemma=DEICIO100) which can be translated as "throw down". Now, the meaning of the verb is negative, as in, it doesn't portray a good action. This would need research on how it reflects in some of the verbs you listed (although the link is clear), but not all verbs starting with "de-" share the same history just because they have the same syllable, see for example "decimeter" and "dead".

Comment: Don't forget ruthless!

Comment: Last I checked, the "in" of "infernal" isn't a prefix, but part of the stem "infern", meaning "below" ('cause that's where it is).

Comment: @Pacerier the _de-_ in decrement is the negative of the _in-_ in increment.  Similarly almost all of those verbs are in fact negations.

Comment: @NoName indeed.  Similarly, many of the in- and im- words have the prefix "in-" meaning "in," rather than the "in-" that means "not," so they're not negative at all, e.g. impetuous, impromptu, inhibited, invert.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not certain what to call them, unless you accept *loanwords* as the answer. Of course these aren't just any loanwords; these are loanwords from languages that share cognate roots with English. For example, *nonplussed* and its noun form *nonplus* come from the Latin words *nōn* and *plūs*, meaning "no" and "more"; English has incorporated both *non-* and *nonplus*, but not *plus*. (At least in the sense of the anti-negation of *nonplus* -- of course English did incorporate *plus*, but separately, so that the two are unrelated.) So *nonplus* **is** the negation of *plus*, but only in another language!

I'll add that, as Alenanno has demonstrated, not all words with this property are loanwords.

Comment: I don't think "loan words" fit that definition. Loan words are words taken from other languages, and you can't find any "words that look like a negative but they aren't" in their definition.

Comment: That's why I said I didn't know what to call them. But do you disagree that they are loan words, and that their peculiar properties arise from that fact?

Comment: Some loan words might have that feature, but so can other "normal" words as well! What I meant is that such feature is not peculiar of loan words.

Comment: Perhaps, but the examples JeffSahol offered (_wittingly_ has its own entry in the _OED_, so I don't count it) all fall into this category; and I can't think of any examples of "normal" words that have this property. I'd be fascinated to learn of some.

Comment: I'm going to write an answer for this.