# Confusing meanings of "inexorable" and "unstoppable"

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

I saw these two words, which I had always assumed meant the same thing, in the same sentence (below). It begs a question as to the difference between them:

Sentence:

> This restless and perpetual change, as **inexorable** and **unstoppable** as the waves and tides, implies a world in which all human actions necessarily have uncertain effects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Inexorable** means unresponsive to entreaty, or unrelenting.  In other words, you can *ask* the waves and tides to stop, but they won't.  In addition, the connotation is that the effect is a negative one--an inexorable decay.

**Unstoppable** has no such personification aspect to it, and its effect is not necessarily negative.  You could have unstoppable fortitude.

Comment: +1 Well said. Two small points: 1. you might want to add that, besides this difference in connotation, they are near-synonyms, as in the OP's example sentence; and 2. I always imagine someone praying on his knees when I use or read *inexorable*, so *entreaty* or *begs* would seem even more fitting than the slightly weaker *asks*. "Stop quaking, you stupid earth, I beg of y— *ughh...*"

Comment: Interesting: I thought *inexorable* would be one of those [unpaired words](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27563/what-do-you-call-words-that-look-like-a-negation-but-are-not), but *exorable* does exist as a word, too.

Answer (score 2):

It's a good example of how semantic shift takes place. The two words are arranged as a sort of duplication, and in a sense, they do. This duplication emphasizes the meaning of either word. Great.

But they don't always mean the same thing, as pointed out above. So near-synonyms or sometime-synonyms are taken by a hearer as identical in content or interchanged inappropriately. Thus, inexorable comes to be used as "unstoppable" when it means "can't be exhorted," which isn't exactly the same thing - after all, perhaps a stubborn mule refuses to be exhorted into movement, that is, to start. In point of fact, though, we'd all think it was strange if we heard about the inexorable mule *refusing to start*.